# Query record and subtract date from query from today()

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I want to display the oldest record in my custom object “Application”

With a query I can grab the oldest record to the position “Entry":

```
 SELECT Id, Name, Date_Applied__c FROM Application__c WHERE Position_Level__c =‘Entry’ Order By Date_Applied__c ASC Limit 1
```

I then want to take that record and subtract it by today() to show how old the record is so:

```
Date_Applied__c = 9/01/2018
Today - 9/10/2018 
Result should be= 9 days old
```

How can I get the results after querying the record then show it in a visual force page?

I want it to look like this basically:

```
Oldest Entry Application:
        9 Days Old
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOQL doesn't support that kind of data manipulation. You've got two primary options:

1. Wrap your queried data rows in an Apex wrapper class, which would have a calculated property like

`public Date ageInDays { get { return Date.today() - myApplication.Date_Applied__c } }`

and modify your Visualforce page accordingly to iterate over a `List<wrapperClass>` rather than a `List<Application__c>`.

2. Add a formula field to your `Application__c` object like `Age_in_Days__c`:

`TODAY() - Date_Applied__c`

Then, just query that field in your controller and display it like any other field.

Comment: HI I created the formula field but while displaying it on my Visualforce page it comes up blank:  <apex:outputText  value="{!myApplication.Age_in_Days__c}" />

Comment: Is `Date_Applied__c` blank? Did you grant yourself FLS to that field?